# How can I get Instagram accounts information without Access Token

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am Live In the middle east and I have both Instagram and Facebook accounts and they are linked to each other. but in the developer's section, where asks for a phone number to register and generate **Access Token** My country is not on that list therefore registration and authentication fail.

I need to read information like

```
Instagram public info and bio
Followers list 
Following list

If there are posts
      post's likes(count and likers)
      post's likes(count and content and interacts)
```

It seems these are available by the Access token but I cannot generate it.
I tried to use Virtual number but Facebook mostly knows them and it failed.
Is there any way to do that?
Any Kind of Help is welcome

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: @mrodo the programing language is less matter javascript, PHP or python all are works to solve my problem.

Comment: I had the same Issue too.